# I can't access a shared file that is in a google shared drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Python to list out files shared with my google service account.

The process is working fine except that one file that I know is shared with my service account is not coming up in the output list.

The file is not owned by me so there is a limit to what I can show and trial, the one thing I have noticed is that the problem file "belongs to a shared drive" whereas the others do not. Also the "share" interface is very different to the one I am used to, I think again due to it being in a shared drive space.

Screenshots, the problem file share interface is all red/maroon unlike the normal ice blue/grey you get.

Shared drive file: share file interface
[image: problem file]

Non shared drive file: share interface
[image: normal file]

When I share the file with a "normal" google account it comes up in the drive UI in the shared with me area no issue.

My guess is there is some sort of hierarchy of permissions on the drive that is blocking my service account, hopefully though there is a simpler solution.

**Things I've tried:**

I have already asked the owner to add my service account email themselves, this did not change anything.

I have tried various string query changes like "sharedWithMe" and also looking in the appData location as well as drive.

If I share the file with a normal google user I can access it through the google drive "shared with me" area, so it is definitely "shared".

If I copy the file to my own area and share the file with the service account, the copy does appear in the output.

**listing files code for reference**

```py
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
api_name = 'drive'
api_version = 'v3'

##### I have a separate service builder function that is working fine

results = self.service.files().list(
        pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, shared, 
        mimeType)").execute()
self.files = results.get('files', [])
if not self.files:
        print('No files found.')
else:
        print('Files:')
        for file in self.files:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(file['name'], file['id']))
```

I expect the shared drive file to be listed in the output, but it is not. Other files are listing correctly.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue at all, I'm able to list all shared files with my Service account using `results = service.files().list(pageSize = 10, fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)').execute()` regardless of whether the file has been created or owned by a user inside my domain or not. Which user's email are you using when you call `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_file(srvAccMail, p12FilePath, pass, [scopes]).create_delegated('email')`, yours or your Service Account's?

Comment: Hi Rafa, as mentioned I am hitting a problem accessing a file inside a shared drive area of an external domain. Normal shared files come up no problem regardless of creator / owner. I am calling the service as the service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the files on a shared Drive, you must specify the Drive ID in the [`files: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method using the a `driveId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` parameter.

You can first obtain this by using the `Drives: list` method provided by the Google Drive REST API [as you can see here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list).

You can get a list of the files on a specific shared drive with the following code:

```
def getSharedDriveFiles(service):

    service = create_directory_service("Service_Account_Email")

    results = service.drives().list().execute()
    items = results.get('drives', [])

    driveIDs = []

    if not items:
        print('No files found')
    else:
        print('Drives:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
            driveIDs.append(item['id'])

    results = service.files().list(pageSize = 10, fields='nextPageToken, files(name, id)', driveId='SHARED_DRIVE_ID', corpora='drive', includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        print('No files found')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

I made sure that my service account's email was added to the list of users the Drive is shared with and I was able to get an output of all the files in the Drive regardless of which domain the owner of the file is a member of.

Comment: this is good to know! I think I have found an extra piece of information that could be part or the real fix. I don't think the client has API access enabled for their account. I imagine this would block my access, if I get them to turn that on would I still need this fix also? As I am writing out a process for data processing it would be good if I didn't have to maintain a drive / client map for accessing files.

Comment: I ran this code and came up with an empty drive list so I suspect the lack of API access on their account is my main limit at the moment.

Comment: Okay, let me know if you have problems once the API access has been allowed. Are you getting `No files found` printed in console? You can try putting the function code inside a `try{ doThis(); }; catch(e){ Logger.log("Error = " + e); };` to see if you're getting an Error is this is not the case.

Comment: Hi Rafa, sadly my client got back to me and confirmed that API access is enabled, so it doesn't look like that is my problem. `>>> gd.service.drives().list().execute() ` returns back to me `{u'kind': u'drive#driveList', u'drives': []}` so it looks like it is clear of errors. Unfortunately I am still stuck though.

Comment: @theduxinlux Can you check to see if the service account can access the file itself by using something like a `Files: copy` or `Files: get` request? The share permissions for the file itself may be different to that of the Drive it's contained in as Drive doesn't use a filesystem and share permissions aren't inherited.

Comment: you beautiful man! It was as simple as that. If I direct access the file I am good. It is a bit of a shame as it means I can't do automated listing and processing but I guess for that I need to get my API account added at the drive level and not the file level. Hmm, now how to give you the answer credit...

Comment: @theduxinlux No worries! Have you looked into Drive permissions API? If you use it to query the permissions of the Drive and the file you might be able to see if the issue lies there https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions

Comment: Giving this one the answer although the answer is actually in the comment chain

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to get the filename without having access to the folder/drive? Once I've downloaded the file I would like to save it with the same filename locally.